# Including a Playground in my project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm working in Xcode 9 on a Swift project, and I'm in table flipping mode with this.

Here's my end goal: put my tests next to my logic in a playground so that as I write the logic, I can see the tests pass in close to real time.

I will also accept how to put my tests in a playground by themselves, I just don't want to be running tests on a simulator for every little thing.

My problems in trying to get this to work are many. First and foremost, I can't find a way to add a playground directly to my project/workspace. When I right click on a group in the project navigator and select 'New file...' I get this:

[image: New file dialog]

As you can see, no option for playground. Filtering also returns no results. If I press the plus button at the bottom of the project navigator, the same dialog (with no playground option) pops up.

I thought it's in another menu so I went to the File menu, and in "New >" I find an option for creating a playground. I select a blank playground from the chooser, choose where to save it (strange that it wanted to save it under 'Unsaved Xcode Documents') and a basic playground comes up in a new tab. Odd thing I notice, though, is that there's no longer a play button or scheme/simulator selector at the top on this tab.

It now doesn't recognize ANY modules other than Apple provided ones! And sure enough, creating the playground didn't actually add it to my workspace. I guess I have to manually add it to my project. Upon doing so, it will recognize my pods *but none of my project files*! Any class I try to use gives me an `Unrecognized identifier`. Trying to `import` my project doesn't work either, it just gives me a `No module`.

I tried clearing `DerivedData`, I tried cleaning, I tried restarting Xcode, I even made sure I had an iPad Pro in the list of simulators (since that seems to matter for some people).

In frustration, I deleted the playground, and resolved just to deal with running my tests constantly. But now, my project has persistent errors! Despite moving the playground to the trash, Swift continues to error saying 'Unresolved identifier' for that playground!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the excellent [Brandon Williams](http://fewbutripe.com) says in his talk at [FrenchKit](http://frenchkit.fr/), a playground "[does not get access to anything in the application target.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrdxSNG-_DE&feature=youtu.be&t=425)" Which is ridiculous, but hey, what are you gonna do. So the answer is: there is currently no way to do this the way I asked.

It IS possible, however, to achieve this functionality if your logic is in its own framework/cocoapod. That is, move the logic you want to test *out of your app target* and into an outside library that your app, subsequently, imports. This will allow your playground to import it as well, and you can test to your heart's content.